# how to config http as default request in WSO2 Identity server

Tags: http, https, wso2, wso2-identity-server

As default Config during WSO IDentity Server (WSO2 IS). we can access to admin by the https request with the port 9443 with the below link:

https://localhost:9443/carbon/

But as mentioned on the below link.we can access through Http request with port 9763. But when we access with the http request, It will redirect automatically to https.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Default+Ports+of+WSO2+Products

I also tried to find and see a confit relating to http and https in IS_HOME/responsitory/conf/axis2.xml.

```
<transportReceiver name="https"
                   class="org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.http.HttpsTransportListener">
    <parameter name="port">9443</parameter>
</transportReceiver>
<transportReceiver name="http"
                   class="org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.http.HttpTransportListener">
    <parameter name="port">9763</parameter>
</transportReceiver>
```

I tried to comment a config relating to https and build again but the result is not good when I had exception here.

I want to ask how to config in WSO2 IS to use HTTP as default to access instead of HTTPS as the initial config.

I would be happy if y can support me in this case.
Thanks.

Comment: Although the axis2.xml file contains configurations for HTTP/S transports by default, they are not used by WSO2 products. Instead, the products use the HTTP/S transport configurations in Tomcat-level; therefore, changing the HTTP/S configurations in the axis2.xml file has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable HTTP access to management console Open carbon.xml located at WSO2_HOME/repository/conf directory and uncomment the following line.

```
<EnableHTTPAdminConsole>true</EnableHTTPAdminConsole>
```

Now you should be able to login. See the following.[image]

Comment: Oh, I tried and can access successfully from browser with http requests. But I can't login with account into System while with these account, I can login with the link which includes https request

Comment: I could successfully login to the system. I have attached a screenshot. Have you done any other config change?

Comment: What is the IS version?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I can log in to Management Portal if I make HTTPS request on port 9443 but I cannot if I make http request on 9763.

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions of WSO2 IS, follow the below steps to enable HTTP access to management console.

Go to the $IS_HOME/repository/conf and open carbon.xml, and uncomment

```
<EnableHTTPAdminConsole>true</EnableHTTPAdminConsole>
```

Disable secure cookie parameter in $IS_HOME/repository/conf/tomcat/carbon/WEB-INF/web.xml file.

```
<session-config> 
 <cookie-config> 
  <secure>false</secure> 
 </cookie-config> 
</session-config>
```

Comment: If your IS version is using the deployment.toml file, then you will have to update the .j2 template in order to override the carbon.xml with <EnableHTTPAdminConsole>true</EnableHTTPAdminConsole>. 

The .j2 is located in the $IS_HOME/repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/carbon.xml.j2